How to use VB.Net and GetFileInfo with file name containing double quote mark?
I'm writing a tool for migrating data from SQL Server to SQLite. The data concerns music files and I need to get the file length (not stored in the SQL Server database) during the migration. I've been using My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo and it has worked like a champ until I ran across some file names with double quote characters in them (the " character means 'inches' in these file names as the music files are from 7-inch or 12-inch singles in these cases). When I call My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo or FileInfo with such a file name, vb.net throws an exception. Is there a way of forcing either method to accept double quotes or any other method to call for getting file lengths that will work?
I am using Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit), version 17.4.3 with VB.Net. This is a Windows application, using .NET 6.0 framework, targeting and supporting OS version 7.0.
By the way, the disco tunes referenced in the example are NOT from my private collection! Don't go disco-shaming me!
The string variable filePath contains:

V:\CDs\Disco\Summer, Donna\2003 The Journey- The Very Best of Donna Summer\21. I Feel Love (12" single mix).flac

The code I'm using that bombs out is:
Dim infoReader As System.IO.FileInfo = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(filePath)

or
Dim info As New FileInfo(filePath)

The error thrown is:

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. : 'V:\CDs\Disco\Summer, Donna\2003 The Journey- The Very Best of Donna Summer\21. I Feel Love (12" single mix).flac'


What does OS version 7.0 mean?

According to Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces a double quote is a reserved character and can't be used in a file name. It's easy to verify this. Open Notepad. Attempt to save with a filename containing a double quote or in Windows File Explorer, right-click an existing file and attempt to rename it with a double quote in the filename.

Does IO.FileInfo(String) also get upset?

I'm not in a position to check right now but I would have thought that Windows would not allow a double-quote in a file name and the comment above seems to confirm that. Can you actually see these file names in File Explorer? If so, exactly what type of drive are they on, including OS, and how were they created?

The FileInfo and GetFileInfo methods both throw the same error. I can definitely see the double quotes in File Explorer. The files are on either internal hard drives or external, USB-attached hard drives, both formatted to NTFS. The OS is Windows 11 on my main computer or Windows 10 on another computer I have. I am able to open these files in media-playing apps such as JRiver Media Player or VLC Media Player. "OS Version 7.0" earlier is what Visual Studio says the Target OS version is in the application properties.  I guess it means 32-bit Windows, which is what SQLite seems to need.

@Jerry How did the string get into the variable filePath? Did the computer supply it (e.g., from using Directory.GetFiles) or did you type it in?

I can actually call My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(filePath)         MsgBox(infoReader.FullName) as well as New FileInfo(filePath) in a .NET 8 application with this illegal filename without getting an exception. Are you sure the exception occurs on these very code lines? Note that you have to escape the double quote in a string constant by repeating the double quote: Dim filePath As String = "V:\CDs\...\21. I Feel Love (12"" single mix).flac". (Not doing so would lead to a compilation error, not to an exception).

Maybe replace the double quotes by 2 apostrophes which are valid characters?
